# microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2013

I cant connect my database (`ms access`) to `visual studio 2010`

```
MS Access 2013
Visual Studio 2010
```

Im running on `Windows 8 64bit`

I got this error when i hit the Test Connection button

```
"microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0 provider is not registered on the local machine"
```

Thanks is advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you need to install the driver 
Follow link to download !

[Driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734)
 If this doesn't work see here [Microsoft workaround](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine?forum=vstsdb)

Comment: I install that already the AccessDatabaseEngine and its not still working :(